# If $f \in \mathcal{o}(g)$, does $f \circ g \in \mathcal{o}(g \circ f)$?

Tags: asymptotics

It's a widely known fact that $\lambda n. \left\lfloor \lg n! \right\rfloor \in \mathcal{O}(\lambda n. \left\lfloor \lg n \right\rfloor!)$. Is it also true (I tried and haven't found a counterexample so far) for all functions $f$ and $g$ satisfying $f \in \mathcal{o}(g)$, not just $f(n) = \left\lfloor \lg n \right\rfloor$ and $g(n) = n!$? If so, does the result still hold with $\mathcal{o}$ replaced by $\mathcal{O}\setminus\Theta$? And under what condition can the conclusion be strengthened with $\mathcal{o}$ or $\mathcal{O}\setminus\Theta$ in place of $\mathcal{O}$?

Comment: Is the swapped order of $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ in your title intentional?

Comment: Definitely intentional!

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, you can post them separately.  It's confusing that the title doesn't match the body.

Comment: They're so much related that I thought it'd be fine. (The alternative is to have multiple almost identical questions.) But I'm clearly not as versed in this community ad you are, so I'll try to remember.

Yes, as I wrote in the comment under the first answer, I made a mistake in one character in the title. At SO they explained to me that edits shouldn't change what's asked, even to correct a glaring discrepancy, and even to say what was intended from the beginning. So I presume the same rule holds here.

Comment: "It's a widely known fact that $\lambda n. \left\lfloor \lg n! \right\rfloor \in \mathcal{O}(\lambda n. \left\lfloor \lg n \right\rfloor!)$": widely ? Really ? And what is the connection to the question ?

Comment: It seems to be widely known to people who learned this stuff at a university. At least where I come from. And the connection is that it provides an example of something for which I asked if a counterexample existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relation between $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ in general.

- If $f(n) = n^2$ and $g(n) = n^3$, then $f \circ g = g \circ f$
- If $f(n) = \log n$ and $g(n) = n^2$, then $f \circ g \in o(g \circ f)$.
- If $f(n) = \log n$ and $g(n) = \sqrt n$, then $f \circ g \in \omega(g \circ f)$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Try $f(x)=\sqrt x$ and $g(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Then both of the compositions are the identity function. A function is $\mathcal O$ of itself. So not a counterexample.

Comment: Oh, I see I wrote `o` with the wrong capitalization in the title. Disregard it. (There's a rule that edits cannot change the essence, so it has to stay.) The body contains the actual problem I'm asking.